# Does Dropbox API support user account and subscription creation?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Does Dropbox API support creation of user accounts, subscriptions, subscriptions changing, etc? For example, can I make an app that users can use to purchase some Dropbox products?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Does-Dropbox-API-support-user-account-and-subscription-creation/m-p/405479#M22062 ]

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting Gregs' answer from Dropbox forum:

> Yes, Dropbox resellers can create and manage Dropbox accounts. Please
>   [sign up here](https://www.dropbox.com/business/partners) if you're interested in doing so.